# Proving cross product identities

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

In my textbook, the author claims that the following can be proved by chaining vector triple product and scalar triple product

$$\text{i.) }(A \times B) \cdot (C \times D) = (A \cdot C)(B \cdot D) - (A \cdot D)(B \cdot C)$$

$$\text{ii.) }A \times [B \times (C \times D)] = B[A \cdot (C \times D)] - (A \cdot B)(C \times D)$$

I can prove both by writing out the component form but cannot derive the identity by chaining the rules

for example

$$A \times [B \times (C \times D)] = A \times (C(B \cdot D) - D(B \cdot C)) $$

$$= A \times (C(B \cdot D)) - A \times (D(B \cdot C))$$

after that triple product rule is non applicable, am I missing something?

Comment: From which identities exactly do you want to derive these?

Comment: The author just introduced dot product and cross product along with triple product, so I think the examples can be prove by those

Comment: Are you sure that (ii) is typed correctly? Applying the vector triple product to the LHS of (ii) gives you the first term on the RHS of (ii) and $A[B \cdot (C \times D)]$, which is a multiple of $A$; in (ii) this term is a multiple of $C \times D$, and in general these are not multiples of $A$.

Comment: Yeah, I double checked with the textbook, there is no typo, maybe the textbook is incorrect?

Comment: When applying vector triple product to the LHS of ii.) I got $A \times (C(B \cdot D) - D(B \cdot C)) $ and not $B[A \cdot (C \times D)]$ plus $A[B \cdot (C \times D)]$ are those two equivalent?

Comment: I checked in components and (ii) really does hold. Notice there are two ways to apply the triple cross product identity to the LHS of (ii), since there are actually three cross products there, on the "outside" or on the "inside".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i) Applying the symmetry
$$X \cdot (Y \times Z) = Y \cdot (Z \times X)$$
to $X = A \times B, Y = C, Z = D$ gives
$$(A \times B) \cdot (C \times D) = (D \times (A \times B)) \cdot C.$$
Now, applying the triple vector product identity
$$D \times (A \times B) = A (D \cdot B) - B (D \cdot A)$$
gives that the right-hand side is
$$[A (D \cdot B) - B (D \cdot A)] \cdot C] = (A \cdot C)(B \cdot D) - (A \cdot D)(B \cdot A)$$
as desired.

(ii) Applying the triple cross product identity to $A$, $B$, and $C \times D$ gives that the left-hand side is
$$A \times (B \times (C \times D))) = B(A \cdot (C \times D)) - (C \times D)(A \cdot B).$$